# When click submit need to show new page in the same page in yii

Tags: yii

In my application setting page is having, in that change password option is having. When i click Change password the password page is showing in current page. But when i click submit without enter fields it showing new page with the message like "fill all fields." But i this message should display in my current page.

```
<?php 
    echo CHtml::ajaxlink('Change Password', 
                          array('/user/password', 'id'=>Yii::app()-user->id),
                          array('update' => '.inner_tab_content'));  
  ?>
```

Comment: Please read through the documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/388/ajax-form-submiting-in-yii/ or just http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/?tag=AJAX

Comment: put code of your controller.